# casting numeric to Text in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, casting

While converting numeric column to TEXT in SQLite, the resultant value has been displayed by appending .0 at the end.
For Eg: 2017 as 2017.0 while converting it to text.
Expected Result: 2017 casting to text will remain as 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast two times to remove the double precision

```
select cast(cast(Sheet1.Sample as int) as varchar);
```

Comment: Since the actual data type of the column is Double, While converting it to TEXT in SQLite. The .0 gets appended. Is this the behavior in SQLite or is there any other way to prevent this appending 0 in the casted column

Comment: Is that the direct result of your raw SQL query or is there something in the middle?

Comment: I just gave, CAST(`Sheet1`.`Sample` AS TEXT) in which the datatype of the column `Sheet1`.`Sample` is double. On casting it to TEXT, returns 123 as 123.0. Is this the behavior?